# Create Geoserver Layer from Openlayers Marker-Array

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, openlayers-3

I'm currently using a js-array to display a big ammount of markers from a MSSQL DB in openlayers. But the performace is too bad and I need a new solution. I thought I can solve this by using geoserver to display a layer with all markers. But I can't quite figure out how to accomplish that.

Amy ideas how I can improve the perfomance of my webapplication?
Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many features, consider making a raster layer instead. For instance, [WMS](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/services/wms/reference.html). GeoServer [supports](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html) MSSQL.

If your markers are static then you can drastically boost yur performance with [caching](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html). This increases the performance multifold, but is only suitable for scenarios where you have "static" content.

Also consider asking on https://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Okay, and how can I create a WMS raster layer with my data from the SQL server? Sorry but I can't find any good tutorial.

**EDIT:** My data isn't quite static but it doesn't change often.

Comment: @ChristianBlättler It is actually quite easy. Configure the database, create a layer, configure a WMS for it. Here's a book I recommend to beginners: http://www.amazon.de/GeoServer-Beginners-Guide-Brian-Youngblood-ebook/dp/B00AV5OXUC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1414674282&sr=8-1&keywords=geoserver

Comment: You don't even need to configure a WMS. Once you have added a datasource to GeoServer, the WMS is essentially ready. Geoserver docs are pretty good. Obviously, once you have a WMS the content becomes static (as lexicore has said), so if you want to interact with the markers, you need another approach, such as cluster/bbox strategy within OpenLayers.

Comment: @JohnBarça I actually meant something different by "static". Like, if you have orthophotos or very static geometry like state borders, you can pre-render it as a tileset and serve it via WMTS. This woul be then extremely fast as almost zero processing will be required. However the OP seems to have markers which are somewhat dynamic, so this won't work so easily (unless you invalidate the cache). And you're absolutely right, GeoServer is very well documented so a WMS layer on a MSSQL data source should be no problem at all.

Comment: @lexicore. Yes. Understood, I have done a lot of work with WMTS and WMS. OP needs to clarify if he needs markers that are dynamic and can be selected or just wants to display. I agree with you on everything :D

Comment: @JohnBarça Seems like it is not quite static. I probably won't cache in this case. Best wishes. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652469/create-geoserver-layer-from-openlayers-marker-array/26652646?noredirect=1#comment41910376_26652646